# animating strokes in an inkpresenter

Tags: c#, silverlight, animation, microsoft.ink

I am trying to animate the colors of strokes in an inkpresenter.  Is there a way to make an animation for each stroke in an inkpresenter?  It seems like storyboards only allow you to modify properties for controls made a design time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboards can only animate dependency properties.  Neither the `DrawingAttributes` property of a `Stroke` class nor the `Color` property of the a `DrawingAttributes` class are dependency properties and henc you can not animate them with a storyboard.